# R Parallel Programming with Two Loops and Storage Results

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a function with two loops involved and the results is two lists of data.

The structure

```
function (){
for (i in 1:50){
    for (j in 1:100){
        "Do something"
        "get results a and b"
        a list
        b list
    }
    "use the series of a and b calculate two parameter A and B"
    "put A and B into their list"
    list A = append(list A, A)
'or'list B = cbind(list B, B)   # I don't know which one is better
}
plot the figure using list A and B

"saving the results"
dataframe = df(listA, listB)
dataframe to csv
}
```

The code needs simulate 5000 times and each step takes at least 1 minutes:

1. I want to run this whole function using parallel programming; I tried `lapply` but it only works well with one loop, if I do so the results is not consistent and the plot can not work, i.e. I cannot get the results;

and I find some parallel code can not work on Windows and some cannot work on Mac, I am confused with those ...

Each steps in the loop is independently so one alternative way I thought is just divide the jobs to do them simultaneously, but I need the results constantly (as the order they should be).

2. To using the data in further plot requirements I need to save the results, I feel trouble with this one(upper here) and also the parallel one;

The way I save the results is looks like a mess.
For example, what I want is:

```
A    B
0    0
0.1  1
1.2  4
3    9
6    12
...  ...
```

but what I got is:

```
    V1
0    0   0.1  1  1.2  4   3    9  6    12  ... ...
```

I don't know how to save two columns data from parallel programming.

Comment: With your vector at the end you can do ```matrix(V1, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)``` to get a 2-column matrix.

Comment: Hi, what is exactly V1 means because I didn't name anyone to V1, if this is the default name for vector where to change it?

Comment: The last output. Save it to a variable ```var_whatever``` and put it in place of the V1 in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using the `foreach` package for tasks like this (check [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/foreach/versions/1.4.4/topics/foreach)). This function is like a for loop, but it works on a cluster. So each for iteration is done separately and is combined afterwards. I made a small example with the structure you are using. You can modify this for your task.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
#number of your cluster precessors, i choosed 4
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
# use for z=1:10 your range, the .combine declares how to combine your dataframe afterwrads,
#.inorder makes sure it's sorted and the values are in the right order (TRUE is default)
df<-foreach(z = 1:10, .combine=rbind, .inorder=TRUE) %dopar%{
    list_b = list()
    list_a = list()
    for (i in 1:50){
      for (j in 1:100){
        #some random task you are doing
        a = i 
        b = 50-i
      }
      #combining them
      list_b= cbind(list_b, b)
      list_a= cbind(list_a, a)
    }
    #make sure you return the values, otherwise they don't get combined by foreach
    return(do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, A=list_a, B=list_b)))
}
#foreach returns nested lists, so you can change it to a dataframe easily
df= as.data.frame(df)
View(df)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! thanks for your denote and explain.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the code by using `foreach`. Initially my code need at least 8 hours (i5 15% usage), now it has been running for also 8 hours (8 vcpu 100% usage) and it still continue, seems the parallel didn't work? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @rewove before you accept an answer you should test whether the answer actually answers your question

Comment: @CPak sorry for accept it fast, but technically the code is executable in parallel, from the usage of CPU. Just don't understand why the running time didn't reduce at all. For `multiprocess` model in Python the performance increased intuitive but for R there might need something else to adjust?